# Java Android app and Node.js + Express.js API

Tags: java, android, node.js, rest

I'm actually developing an Android Application that needs connection to the internet. In my API, I am using Node.js and Express.js to handle simple requests such as login, register, or retrieving data about other users.
I am using multiple HTTP requests type with Express.js, such as POST, GET, PUT, PATCH and DELETE, depending on what the server will have to do.
The server is always returning JSON to the client.

I searched on the internet but I didn't find any Framework made to perform HTTP requests from an Android Application. I know that this is possible with some native Java Objects, but I would like something simple and reliable. As I said before, I need to perform different requests (PUT, POST, GET, DELETE etc...).

I saw the OkHttp framework, but It don't seem to do exactly what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http://square.github.io/retrofit/ which is what I needed.

Comment: It's always a good idea to understand how all this works under the hood before using any frameworks/libraries. That's why I recommended looking into HttpUrlConnection before grabbing something like Retrofit. Downvoting my answer because of that does not seem fair.

Comment: You are perfectly right. Sorry for the downvote (wrong click)

Answer (score 3):

The [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class is everything you need for that. It's not complex so you'll find your way around it pretty quick. The thing you have to think about is asynchronism. [This article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#d23135e41) helps a lot.